# How to loop through PDO Statement and write data on if statements

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, while-loop

Sorry for the convoluted title, but I wasn't really sure how to explain it. I have a database with 138 users, but users 133-138 have been removed from the database for admin purposes. For business purposes, I don't want to change the others' "user id." I have written some scripts to get sale information from MySQL with PDO objects. I count through "count(result)" of the PDO in a foreach loop, when the count equals the 'result2', it write data into a table in mPDF.

This is where the problem starts, it works perfectly until it reaches count 133 where there isn't a user. It doesn't print anything out (as it shouldn't), but then skips the remaining numbers also. It doesn't complete the loops for users 139-146. How do I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("select u.user_id, u.fname, u.lname, d.saledate, d.custname, d.straddr, d.city, d.state, d.zip
from users u
inner join dplgalionsales d
on u.lname = d.agent_last_name
where saledate > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
order by u.user_id asc, saledate asc");
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->fetchAll();
$count = 1;
foreach($res as $result) {
    $size = count($result['user_id']);
    $mydate = date('m/d/Y');
    $dateadd = date('m/d/Y', strtotime($mydate. ' + 3 days'));  
    $html_table = '<div>Week Ending: ' .$mydate. '<br>Payroll Issued: ' .$dateadd. '</div><br>';
    $html_table .= '<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" width="100%"><tr><th>Date</th><th>Customer Name</th><th>Address</th></tr>';
    while($count < $size) {
        if($val == $result['user_id']) {
            $html_table .= '<tr><td>' .$result['saledate']. '</td><td>' .$result['custname']. '</td><td>' .$result['straddr']. ' ' .$result['city']. ' ' .$result['state']. ' ' .$result['zip']. '</td></tr>';
        }
        $count += 1;
    }
    $html_table .= '</table>'; //ends HTML table
    $mpdf = new mPDF();
    $mpdf->SetTitle('DPL Galion Sales');
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html_table);
    if(is_dir('../reports/'.$count.'')) {
        $mpdf->Output('../reports/'.$count.'/DPLOH/'.date('m-d-Y').'_DPLOH_SalesID_'.$count.'.pdf','F');
    }
}
exit;
```

Comment: I think you need to separate the logic that makes use of `$count`, `$size` from the logic that loops through the query result. I am not entirely sure but I think you can get rid of `$count`, `$size` entirely and just use the while/foreach to iterate through the results of the query statement.

Comment: Could you also possibly combine the two query statements into one ?

Comment: I removed the 2nd query, but I need the count to compare against user_id in order to generate a blank PDF and save it for that user or fill the rows in the table if that employee has sold something within the time span.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I didn't get your code at first.

Make it this way

```
$res = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
foreach($res as $user_id => $user_data) {
    $mydate = date('m/d/Y');
    $dateadd = date('m/d/Y', strtotime($mydate. ' + 3 days'));  
    $html_table = '<div>Week Ending: ' .$mydate. '<br>Payroll Issued: ' .$dateadd. '</div><br>';
    $html_table .= '<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" width="100%"><tr><th>Date</th><th>Customer Name</th><th>Address</th></tr>';
    foreach ($user_data as $result) {
        $html_table .= '<tr><td>' .$result['saledate']. '</td><td>' .$result['custname']. '</td><td>' .$result['straddr']. ' ' .$result['city']. ' ' .$result['state']. ' ' .$result['zip']. '</td></tr>';
    }
    $html_table .= '</table>'; //ends HTML table
    $mpdf = new mPDF();
    $mpdf->SetTitle('DPL Galion Sales');
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html_table);
    if(is_dir('../reports/'.$user_id.'')) {
        $mpdf->Output('../reports/'.$user_id.'/DPLOH/'.date('m-d-Y').'_DPLOH_SalesID_'.$user_id.'.pdf','F');
    }
}
```

Comment: I removed the query, but I don't think I explained what I'm trying to do very well. The program iterates through a list of users, the client wants a blank PDF generated if the employee doesn't have any sales results so they see their results for the span of time. The only way I can understand to control those results is through a count which I compare against the "user_id" (which is just a number I assigned... 1 through 146). It creates a PDF for each employee, but breaks when count doesn't equal the result and stops generating PDFs.